# Visible text of UITextView in UIScrollView which has subview UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uitextview

when typing in the UITextView the text is not visible;
when typing is done the text is not visible.

How to make it visible?

The code is below. I do not put the UITextView related code intentionally as only font and alignment properties are set.

```
// Setup the background image view.
[self.backgroundImageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.backgroundImageView];

// Set the image view.
CGRect r = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.TextView.bounds.size.width, 455);
ImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:r];

// Set up the scroll view for the image zooming in/out and scrolling.
imgScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:ImageView.bounds];

[imgScrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[imgScrollView setClipsToBounds:YES];
[imgScrollView addSubview:ImageView];
[imgScrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[imgScrollView setContentSize:ImageView.frame.size];
imgScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5.0;
imgScrollView.delegate = self;

UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scrollViewDoubleTapped:)];
doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[imgScrollView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapRecognizer];

[imgScrollView sendSubviewToBack:self.TextView];

[self.view addSubview:imgScrollView];
```

UPDATE

```
[imgScrollView addSubview:self.TextView];
```

the line of code above solved this.

Comment: There is no `UITextView` in your code

Comment: Solved. See the update.